# How to make a simple calculator in python?

Tags: python

First my codes are from this link 
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/calculator

When i open the program whatever choice I make it prints me invalid input. Am I missing something?
However when I do it on Codeskulptor I do not get it but get the answer i am looking for?
Note: I am using ubuntu and I am trying on Terminal.

Comment: are you using python 2.7 or 3? this code is written for python 3.

Comment: learn about polish notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation
also you can use google : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79795/reverse-polish-notation-calculator-in-python

Comment: I am using 3. Indeed i really do not know which one. I may have both. Is there a way to open it only with python 3?

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) is probably the easiest approach:

```
while True:
    data = input('Enter operation: ')
    print(eval(data))
```

Comment: Where exactly am I supposed to write it. See I am all new to programming

Comment: @user96369 Write all this code into a new Python file, copy-paste then execute it (run it).

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
num1 = float(input('Enter a number: '))
the_operation = str(input('choose operator: '))
num2 = float(input('Enter an anathor number: '))
if the_operation == '*':
   print(num1 * num2)
elif the_operation == '+':
   print(num1 + num2)
elif the_operation == '-':
    print(num1 - num2)
elif the_operation == '/':
    print(num1 / num2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("There must be a space between the number and the operator!!\nBlank to continue\n")
def calc(a,b,c):
    if b in '+-*/':
        if b=='+':
            d=a+c
        if b=='-':
            d=a-c
        if b=='*':
            d=a*c
        if b=='/':
            if c==0:
                d="undefind"
            else:
                d=a/c
        return "Answer:- {}".format(d)
    else:
        return "Invalid operator '{}' !".format(b)
while True:
    cal=input("Type here:- ").split()
    if len(cal)!=3:
        print("Try again!")
        continue
    num1,op,num2=cal[:]
    print(calc(float(num1),op,float(num2)))
    if input("Going to next calculation or not\n::- ").strip()!='':
        break
```

Comment: Thats a lot of code here! Could you write a short paragraph, explaining your code?

Comment: Okay I will do it